# Include jQuery plugin in Ionic

Tags: jquery, html, ionic-framework

I'm making my first Ionic app, and I'm trying to include a jQuery plugin - a slider.

However even if the images load and the JQ/CSS links are there the script won't work. I'm trying to implement this: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/jEpxqJ on my 
home.html page.

On index.html I do this in the header:

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>    
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>      
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>    
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="css/flik.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js'></script>
```

However it looks like this: [image]

When it should be looking like in the codepen link.

Comment: any error in console ? include jquery.js before all js

Comment: No errors, just a warning: Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details. I changed the order and same thing.